# No select2/compat/inputData

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using Select2JS 4.0.5 with PHP and jQuery 3.2.1. jQuery is included first, then right after that select2js then after that the rest of JS libraries. My code

```
if ($("#company").length > 0){   // The code below works with typeaheadJS
$('#company').select2()({
source: function (query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "common/search.php",
            data: 'query=' + query,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                asyncResults($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return item;
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

I keep getting `Error: No select2/compat/inputData`

Similar questions said that if I include the full version instead this error will be fixed. I if I do that, the error would become

`TypeError: $(...).select2(...) is not a function`

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: @MickaelLeger no, i switched to https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: Ok, that's strange I have an other project where I use select2 on input and no problem, but I just try to change my "input" for a "select" and now it works

Answer (score 31):

Changing from an `input` tag to a `select` tag worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

You need to include the full version, `select2.full.js`
This version support input type and not just the select.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of:

```js
import 'select2'
```

I did:

```js
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full'
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify if you don't have others places the Id `#company`

I had this problem and i find another component using the same Id in my page

Comment: This is a comment not an answer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33026902)

Comment: This is possible answer as it can produce this error if you are using same ID in modal view and in master view.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first two brackets after "select2":

```
$('#company').select2({
```

Comment: @MoritzRingler yes you are right, so the correct one must be like: $('#company').select2({

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution to your exact problem, but it may help someone with this error.

Using Razor Pages.

Before rendering, add *your own* `id` attribute to the `@Html.DropDownListFor()`. It seems to be that the default one used by the helper does not work.

In your view:

```cs
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.SelectedFile, Model.GetFilesSelectList(), "Select item", new { @id= "SelectedFileId" })
```

Notice that in this case, normally the `id` generated would be "SelectedFile". We are overwriting that with `new { @id= "SelectedFileId" } dictionary`.

And in your JS make the usual selection:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Variable assignment
    var $producerSelect = $('#SelectedProducerId');
    var $fileSelect = $('#SelectedFileId');

    // Initialize your dropdownlists...
)};
```